# Increase the 9 patch border width fit for all width x height box size

Tags: photoshop, nine-patch, roku

I have a problem to create 9 patch image as to increase the size of border width. when I increase its border width it may not fit for every width and height box size but when i used this image it fitted in every width and height box size. [image]

What is the problem how i increase the 9 patch border width x height box size

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this in Rowlist or in markupgrid anywhere use focusBitmapBlendColor property.